# Is there a function in JQuery that returns a filename selected by the user from his disk?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for some function in jQuery that, when called, would open a "please select a file" or "files" option in the browser for the user to make a choice, and then return the file name and path.

Comment: That may not be possible at all any more, because the browser will give you the file but not its path, for security reasons

Comment: What do you mean by "file but not its path"

Comment: ^^^^ What Pekka said, you can't get the path, all browsers return something like "fakepath" instead.

Comment: Which function would return a "fakepath" and what does the fakepath do

Comment: should be pretty obvious...would you want a malicious script knowing where your files are?  Read File API docs  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of making an extension for your browser, there is no way to get the full path.  Either use an extension or some other kind of plugin such as Silverlight, Java, or similar.  I've used a Java Applet to get the file path in the past.

Answer (score -1):

You can't get the filepath, but you can get the file name.

Look at using a plugin like http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html

Comment: What would a plugin add to the situation that a normal file upload field doesn't already do?

Answer (score -1):

Try following code

```
<input type="file" id="file1" />

$("#file1").change(function(e) {
    var fileName = $(this).val().split('/').pop().split('\\').pop();
    alert(fileName);
});
```

check the demo here

http://jsfiddle.net/nSf7w/100/

Comment: This would work with one file but he asked about multiple files. I'm upvoting you out of the negative, though!

Comment: @Bill this won't give the full path as requested by the OP. For the reasons we discuss above.

Comment: I was only thinking about the filename since I think at the time the comments made it clear the whole path wasn't possible. Also, hello fellow Philadelphian!

Comment: @Bill why, hello! Greetings from West Philly